# Split Column using Delimiter

Tags: sql, command, extract

I try to extract a value within a column and group these values. For example my table contains a column with the following content:

Column:

- download_*name*_01-01-2000
- upload_*name*_05-10-2013
- upload_*thisisanothername*_09-08-2011
- download_*thisisanothername*_11-11-2013
- upload_*thisisthename*_01-05-2008

So I'd like to extract the names (in italic above) and group this column, what means there'll be a row with "name", "thisisanothername" and a row with "thisisthename". The date behind the names may vary, as well as the length of a name itself. And there might be a prefix (like 'upload' or 'download' in the "Column" above). So I can not use for example SUBSTRING(Column,7,10), because this would cut off the name or would not even extract a part of the name (for example if the prefix is very long).

So is there a way in SQL Server, to extract just the name? All I know is that the name is always between a prefix and the date. I have no idea how to do that with my basic SQL knowledge.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edit your subject to ** Split Column using Delimiter **

Comment: @user3797213: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming that the length of the date is always 10

```
create table t1 ( col varchar(100) )

insert into t1 values ('download_name_01-01-2000')
insert into t1 values ('upload_name_05-10-2013')
insert into t1 values ('upload_thisisanothername_09-08-2011')
insert into t1 values ('download_thisisanothername_11-11-2013')


SELECT substring(col, charindex('_', col)+1, len(col) - (charindex('_', col) + 1) - 10)
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 0):

[sURESH bLOG](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/07/sql-server-split-function-example-in.html)

I Think this could help you to perform this by writing a custom split function in sql server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items nvarchar(4000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT
DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)
-- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
--     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
SELECT @INDEX = 1
WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN
-- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
-- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
IF @INDEX !=0
SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
ELSE
SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
-- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)
-- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
-- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
```

**Query**

```
SELECT items FROM [dbo].[Split] ('861,739,10,1670', ',')
```